# Сортировка массива по своим значениям

Tags: php

Всем добрый день, такой вопрос, есть массив который выводит ключ - значение, по алфавиту пример

```
[0] => Волгоград
[1] => Воронеж
[2] => Екатеринбург
```

Мне нужно получить вывод массива в другом порядке, и вывести по полю сортировка числу от меньшего к большему, по тем числам, что указаны в другом массиве:

Другой массив имеет такой тип данных:

```
[CITIES_LIST] => Array
        (
            [1001] => Array
                (
                    [NAME] => Екатеринбург
                    [SORT] => 110
                )

            [29] => Array
                (
                    [NAME] => Воронеж
                    [SORT] => 110
                )

            [49] => Array
                (
                    [NAME] => Волгоград
                    [SORT] => 120
                )
```

Т.Е. Екатеринбург по полю SORT должен стать на первое место по этому массиву
Скажите как это сделать?

Спасибо!

Comment: Как-то непонятно. Вы хотите отсортировать второй массив по значениям из первого массива? или речь идёт о сортировке именно второго массива?

Answer (score 0):

А с чего вы взяли, что по нужному вам алгоритму будет первым `Екатеринбург`? Если в первую очередь вы сортируете по ключу  `SORT` то первым будет 'Воронеж' т.к после сортировки по `SORT`, при одинаковых значениях - 110 интерпретатор дополнительно отсортирует массив  по алфавиту т.е первым будет  `Воронеж`, пример (на скорую руку):

```
$arrays['CITIES_LIST'] = array(
    '29' => array(
        'NAME'=> 'Воронеж',
        'SORT'=> '110'
        ),
    '49' =>  array(
        'NAME'=> 'Волгоград',
        'SORT'=> '120'
        ),
    '1001' =>  array(
        'NAME'=> 'Екатеринбург',
        'SORT'=> '110'
        ),
    
    );


 uasort($arrays['CITIES_LIST'], function ($a, $b) { return $a['SORT'] - $b['SORT']; });
```

> Результат

```
 print_r($arrays['CITIES_LIST']);
 
Array
(
    [29] => Array
        (
            [NAME] => Воронеж
            [SORT] => 110
        )

    [1001] => Array
        (
            [NAME] => Екатеринбург
            [SORT] => 110
        )

    [49] => Array
        (
            [NAME] => Волгоград
            [SORT] => 120
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант:

```
<?php
    
    $arr1 = array(
        0 => 'Волгоград',
        1 => 'Воронеж',
        2 => 'Екатеринбург',
        );
        
    $arr2 = array (

        1001 => Array
            (
                'NAME' => 'Екатеринбург',
                'SORT' => 110,
            ),

        29 => Array
            (
                'NAME' => 'Воронеж',
                'SORT' => 110
            ),

        49 => Array
            (
                'NAME' => 'Волгоград',
                'SORT' => 120,
            ),
        
        );
        
// простой вывод значений в нужном порядке        
    foreach ($arr2 as $key=>$value ) {
        
     if ( in_array( $value['NAME'], $arr1  ) ) {
         
         echo $value['NAME']. "\r\n";
         
     }
     
        
        
    }
    
    
    // создаем массив с ключами
foreach ($arr2 as $key=>$value ) {
        
     if ( in_array( $value['NAME'], $arr1  ) ) {
         
         $arr3 [ array_search( $value['NAME'], $arr1 ) ] =  $value['NAME'];
         
     }
     
        
        
    }
    
    
    var_dump ($arr3);
```

Результат:

```
Екатеринбург
    Воронеж
    Волгоград
    
array(3) {
      [2]=>
      string(24) "Екатеринбург"
      [1]=>
      string(14) "Воронеж"
      [0]=>
      string(18) "Волгоград"
    }
```